# integrator outputing velocity

Tags: operational-amplifier, signal, simulation, multisim

I'm trying to make a integrator output the velocity receiving an accelerometer signal based on the next design
[image]

But the output seems to be fixed on a certain level as showed here
[image]

I'm thinking the values of the components are way off the proportions, but even so, I was expecting a signal that changes as the integral of acceleration i.e. something with a period,
not something fixed.
What is missing in the design?

PD: the in1 was intended to reach a bode plot but at the end it wasn't used, but this should have no effect in the process.

EDIT: As noted by jsotola and Sanmveg saini there was a shortcircuit but when it is corrected, it still does not give the expected output signal
[image]
[image]

Comment: ckeck your schematic carefully

Comment: in u2 you shorted out inverting input and positive supply.

Comment: Beware of the fact that, estimating the velocity of a moving object by integrating its acceleration will lead you to errors. The acceleration sensor is not perfect: it gives you the instantaneous acceleration plus a little error, let's say 0.01%. That little error gets integrated (i.e. summed) in time and will lead you to errors in the estimation of the velocity. Back in 1997 I worked on a project like yours with Analog Devices' ADXL202 accelerometer: we soon gave up.

Comment: I did something similar to @Enrico, with the same ADXL sensor at around the same time, in fact, and would say the same thing. With enough mechanical constraints, you can use the acceleration as part of a control loop, but you need something else, like low-frequency position data for example, to anchor it to something at DC. Besides that, you have to sort out the readings due to rotational motion (in multiple planes) vs the translational velocity you actually want, so it's quite a chore.